# Infinitely recursive/nested categories tree in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an infinitely nested categories tree in Django.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ParentCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The idea here is that all the categories without a `ParentCategory` are the main ones (level 0). All those who's ParentCategory are from level 0 are level 1, and so on.

The only problem here is that I cannot reference `Category` inside of itself. The error returned is, obviously: `NameError: name 'Category' is not defined` at line 3.

How do I fix this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since model has not yet been created at the time fields are being defined, you can use `self` for referring the same model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Seems to be working! The only "problem" is that you cannot add `non-nullable field 'ParentCategory' to category without a default`. Adding `default=None` will fix it.

if you agree, I’d suggest you edit the answer to include this.

Comment: I tried this solution but My python interpreter is unexpectedly crashing again and again. When we create the section from admin, it doesn't allow us to create very first time. Instead, it allows us to create with None. But after creating 3rd level it crashes